# Help multiplying a multivector by $\sqrt{|\det g|}$

Tags: clifford-algebras

In a previous question ([How can I show $\mathbf{e}_0\mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_2\mathbf{e}_3=\sqrt{|g|}\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669432/how-can-i-show-mathbfe-0-mathbfe-1-mathbfe-2-mathbfe-3-sqrtg-gamm)) it was determined that

$$
\mathbf{e}_0 \wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2 \wedge \mathbf{e}_3=\sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2\wedge \gamma_3
$$

Here, my question pertains to multivectors mixing blades of different grades, such as

$$
\mathbf{u}=v (\mathbf{e}_0 \wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2 )+ b (\mathbf{e}_0 \wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2 \wedge \mathbf{e}_3) = v\sqrt{|\det g[\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2]|} \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2+  b\sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2\wedge \gamma_3
$$

where $\sqrt{|\det g[\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2]|}$ is of "dimension 3" and $\sqrt{|\det g|}$ is of "dimension 4".

---

I am trying to produce a multivector using a curvilinear basis that is invariant with respect to a change of coordinates. Specifically, I wish to multiple $\mathvf{v}$ defined as:

$$
\mathbf{v}=v \gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2+  b\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2\wedge \gamma_3
$$

by $\sqrt{|\det g|}$ such that:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}'=\sqrt{|\det g|} \mathbf{v}&=v \sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2+  b \sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2\wedge \gamma_3
\end{align}
$$

The term $b \sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2\wedge \gamma_3$ is equal to $ b \mathbf{e}_0 \wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2\wedge \mathbf{e}_3$, but what is the (geometric) meaning/interpretation of the term $v \sqrt{|\det g|}\gamma_0 \wedge \gamma_1 \wedge \gamma_2$?

Note that it can also be written as:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{|\det g|}}{\sqrt{|\det g[\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2]|}} \mathbf{e}_0 \wedge \mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2
$$

The general question then, is what is the meaning of this term?

$$
\frac{\sqrt{|\det g|}}{\sqrt{|\det g[\mathbf{e}_0,\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2]|}}
$$