# If $e_1e_2 e_3=\sqrt{|\det g|}\hat{x}_1 \hat{x}_2 \hat{x}_3$ then what is $e_1e_2+e_1e_3$?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, jacobian, clifford-algebras

Let

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1^2=1\\
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2^2=1\\
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3^2=1\\
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2+\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1=0\\
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3+\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1=0\\
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3+\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2=0
$$

Then
$$
\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2 \wedge \mathbf{e}_3=\sqrt{|\det g|}\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3
$$

for reference see my previous question ([How can I show $\mathbf{e}_0\mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_2\mathbf{e}_3=\sqrt{|g|}\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669432/how-can-i-show-mathbfe-0-mathbfe-1-mathbfe-2-mathbfe-3-sqrtg-gamm))

---

My question is what is the following expression in terms of $g$?

$$
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2
$$

Let

$$
g=\pmatrix{
g_{11}&g_{12}&g_{13}\\
g_{21}&g_{22}&g_{23}\\
g_{31}&g_{32}&g_{33}
}
$$

This is what I got so far:

$$
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2&=(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)\\
&=(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)^2+(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)+(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)+(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2
\end{align}
$$

Let us treat each term individually:

1. The part $(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)^2$ is:

$$
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)^2=((g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)^2=-(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})^2
$$

2. The part $(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2$ is:

$$
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2=((g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)^2=-(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})^2
$$

3. The part $(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)&=((g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21}) \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)((g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31}) \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)\\
&=-(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31}) (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1)( \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)\\
&=-(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31}) ( \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)
\end{align}
$$

4. The part $(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2)&=((g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31}) \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)((g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21}) \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)\\
&=-(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21}) (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1)( \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)\\
&=-(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21}) ( \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)\\
&=(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21}) ( \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)
\end{align}
$$

So the cross-terms cancel, and we get a sum of areas:

$$
(\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2+\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_3)^2=-(g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}g_{21})^2-(g_{11}g_{33}-g_{13}g_{31})^2
$$

What is the geometric interpretation of what I have done? Do the cross-terms really cancel for areas even in the midst of arbitrary curved space -- this result so so surprising to me.

Answer (score 0):

I will post a tentative answer, rather than an edit because I think I may have missed the true generalization. The key to proofs of this type is to start with:

$$
\mathbf{e}_i=\sum_{k=1}^n a_i^k \hat{\mathbf{x}}_k
$$

There are a few interesting cases:

---

Suppose $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_1$ and $n=1$, then

$$
\mathbf{e}_1=a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\implies (\mathbf{e}_1)^2= (a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1)^2=(a_1^1)^2
$$

Suppose $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_1$ and $n=2$, then

$$
\mathbf{e}_1=a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1+a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\implies (\mathbf{e}_1)^2=(a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1+a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)^2=(a_1^1)^2+(a_1^2)^2
$$

Suppose $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2$ and $n=1$, then

$$
\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2= (a_1^1 \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) \wedge (a_2^1 \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1)=a_1^1 a_2^1 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1)=0
$$

Suppose $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2  \wedge \dots \wedge \mathbf{e}_m$ and $n=m$, then

$$
\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \mathbf{e}_m = (\det a) \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_m
$$

Now the case closer to our interest:

Suppose $\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2$ and $n=3$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_1\wedge \mathbf{e}_2  &= (a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1+a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2+a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3) \wedge (a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1+a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2+a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3) \\
&= a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1+a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 + a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\\
&\quad+ a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 + a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 + a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\\
&\quad+a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 + a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2+ a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\\
&= a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 + a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \\
&\quad +a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge a_2^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 + a_1^1\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\\
&\quad + a_1^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge a_2^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3+ a_1^3\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge a_2^2\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2\\
&= a_1^1 a_2^2 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2) + a_1^2a_2^1 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) \\
& \quad +a_1^3a_2^1 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) + a_1^1 a_2^3(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)\\
& \quad + a_1^2a_2^3 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)+ a_1^3 a_2^2 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)\\
&= a_1^1 a_2^2 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2) - a_1^2a_2^1 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)  +a_1^3a_2^1 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) - a_1^1 a_2^3(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) + a_1^2a_2^3 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)- a_1^3 a_2^2 (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)\\
&= (a_1^1 a_2^2 - a_1^2a_2^1 )(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2)  +(a_1^3a_2^1  - a_1^1 a_2^3)(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3\wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1) + (a_1^2a_2^3 - a_1^3 a_2^2 )(\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2 \wedge \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3)
\end{align}
$$