# Integrals and wedges

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds

I am trying to understand how to construct an integral is a basic algebraic manner using the following tools. Let $\{ \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1, \dots, \hat{\mathbf{x}}_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis such that $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}_j=\delta^i_j$. Let us define a curvilinear basis:

$$
\mathbf{e}_i=\sum_{k=1}^n a_i^k \hat{\mathbf{x}}_i
$$

Then this relation holds ([ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669432/how-can-i-show-mathbfe-0-mathbfe-1-mathbfe-2-mathbfe-3-sqrtg-gamm)):

$$
\mathbf{e}_1\wedge\dots \wedge \mathbf{e}_n=\sqrt{g} (\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1\wedge \dots\wedge\hat{\mathbf{x}}_n) \tag{1}
$$

We note that this relation has a similar form as the Riemannian volume form:

$$
\omega=\sqrt{g} dx_1\wedge \dots \wedge dx_n \tag{2}
$$

My goal now is to go from (1) to (2).

If I take $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i$ to be a vector part of the tangent space of some manifold $M$, I can make this replacement:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}
$$

which gives me the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \mathbf{e}_n &= (\sum_{k=1}^n a_i^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k})\wedge \dots \wedge (\sum_{j=1}^n a_i^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})\\
&=\sqrt{g} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \wedge \dots \wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}  )
\end{align}
$$

But I do not understand how I can go from $\partial / \partial x_i$ to $dx_i$?

Comment: What do you mean by "go from"? At a point, the differential operators $\partial/\partial x^i$ are vectors that belong to the tangent space at that point, while the 1-forms $dx^i$ are linear functionals on those vectors.

Comment: Here is a crude way to port Riemann integration intuition to a manifold. Each parallelepiped is described by vectors $\partial/\partial x^1,\ldots,\partial/\partial x^n$ that point along half of its edges (consider the 2-d and 3-d cases for intuition). $\sqrt{g}dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n$ is an alternating form that, when "fed" these vectors, yields the $n$-dimensional volume of that parallelepiped: $\textrm{vol}(\textrm{parallelepiped}) = \sqrt{g}(dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n)(\partial/\partial x^1,\ldots,\partial/\partial x^n)$.